# editor formatting problems in sql server 2008 r2

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, code-formatting

When creating a new view in SSMS I inserted nicely formatted SQL code which included CTEs.  As soon as I click into the diagram pane, the SQL code loses alignment no matter which editor options I try. What am I missing?  I'm trying to make the SQL easier to maintain and more readable, but the editor will not cooperate.  Where/How do you preserve formatting?  I appreciate any help!

Comment: Don't use the diagram pane with CTEs. Really, I can't remember the last time I used the diagram at all. If you do need this, save your work before opening the pane, capture your diagram, close the pane, and then revert.

Comment: Create your view in a New Query window. Don't use the visual designers; they're utter crap. They won't keep your formatting because they're trying to "improve" it.

Answer (score 1):

SSMS Query Designer helps you to write a query and it should really be used only when you are writing your a Sql server query for the 1st time :).

When creating views or any other sql server objects use the SSMS query Window to write you code. Once you have created the object next time when you want to get the definition of that object use system stored procedure `sp_helptext`, which will return the code the way you wrote it.

```
EXECUTE sp_helptext objectName
```

Comment: Perfect answer, but to me it sounds more like a workaround. Why doesn't SSMS preserve formatting?!

Comment: Thank you :) . If you have ever written a query in query designer you have probably noticed it as soon as you execute it  in query designer it just changes the formatting, it just not on of its functionalities, And personally I find it very difficult to write a query using query designer, it just doesnt feel right :)

Comment: @PatrickHofman It does preserve formatting. For that, you need to create the view in the query window, **that** format gets preserved. The designer just formats it the way it wants

Comment: Also since query designer does a few things for you like creating joins and join conditions, it would prefer to have code the way it likes :)